# Computation of a functional for large values

Tags: integration, special-functions, oscillations, complex-analysis

Consider the following function :

$$f(x) = \sin^2(\frac{π\Gamma(x)}{2x})$$

Now consider the following functional :

> > $$I(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x + iy) − f(x − iy)}{e^{2πy}-1} dy$$

I need values for of $I(x)$ for large $x$ at least upto 10^2.

I tried it on Mathematica but I couldn't .

Here are some calculated values for small X's :[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkDtF.jpg) [img2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBsS9.jpg)

> > Also if possible , what is the apparent asymptotic of minimas and Maximas of the functional?

Comment: @AloneProgrammer see also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3570663/702232